# Reshape list to match particular dimension in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

I would like to specify some table dimension for a particular list, reshape
to that dimension and then display as a dataframe.

For example, for `_list` above, if I wanted to display that as a `5x5` table
it would look as:

```py
import random
import string

random.seed(1)
N = 21
_list = ["".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 3)) for _ in range(N)]

dimension = 5 * 5
buffer = ["" for _ in range(dimension - len(_list))]
_list = _list + buffer

pd.DataFrame(np.array(_list).reshape(5, 5))
```

which outputs

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  iKZ  Weq  hFW  CEP  yYn
1  gFb  yBM  WXa  SCr  UZo
2  Lgu  bPI  ayR  nBU  bHo
3  WCF  Jow  oRW  Dsb  AJP
4  glO
```

I feel as though this approach is quite clunky though, and that there is a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this and see if it works for you ... the main worker here is [resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize), and setting refcheck to False, since we are not sharing the memory with another array

```
#convert list to an array
num = np.array(_list)

#resize and set refcheck to False
# it is a new object and memory for this array has not been shared with another 
num.resize((5,5), refcheck=False)

#print num
num

array([['iKZ', 'Weq', 'hFW', 'CEP', 'yYn'],
       ['gFb', 'yBM', 'WXa', 'SCr', 'UZo'],
       ['Lgu', 'bPI', 'ayR', 'nBU', 'bHo'],
       ['WCF', 'Jow', 'oRW', 'Dsb', 'AJP'],
       ['glO', '', '', '', '']], dtype='<U3')
```

Have a look at the docs for [resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) - u might find more info better suited for ur use case